# exiftool system cannot find path

Tags: exif, exiftool

I want to use exiftool to change the names of my files in one directory to the creation time (I'm on Windows 10).

- I "installed" exiftool under C:\Windows as recommended.
- I also set the path for exiftool.
- I created a directory under the path `C:\testordner` where I copied all
  my files into.
- I opened the commandline in windows.

When I enter the command: `C:\testordner>exiftool .` everything works and i get the exif data of all files inside this directory.
When I enter the command: `C:\testordner>exiftool IMG_0160.JPG` it works too.

After reading the documentation I tried the following command to change the filenames of all my files in the directory to the creationdate:

```
C:\testordner>exiftool '-FileName<DateTimeOriginal' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M.%S%%-c.%%e" .
```

When I try to run this command I always get the error message: "System cannot find the specified file" (In german: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.)

I also tried:

```
C:\testordner>exiftool '-FileName<CreateDate' -d %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S%%.%%le .
```

What do I do wrong? I don't get it.

Comment: Not urgent anymore. I gave up and wrote my own JAVA program which is way easier :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the exiftool main page, [Running in Windows](https://exiftool.org/#running):

"Note that when typing commands in the "cmd.exe" shell, you should use double quotes instead of single quotes as shown in some examples"

Under Windows CMD, change the single quotes to double quotes and your command works correctly.